# Using SaveChangesAsync feature with non async webapi

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have some webapi written in .net mvc4 and using EF6 , now all my api controllers are not  async , and i wanted to use SaveChangesAsync feature of EF6

My api looks something like

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(#some argument)
{
   ///so some computation and db operations without saving them

   // here i want to save all the db operations i had done above
   db.SaveChangesAsync();//Task 1

  // again do some computation 

  // wait for operation(Task1) to get complelte

  //do some computation

}
```

How can i make use of EF6 SaveChangesAsync() feature without actually changing each of my api controller to async.

Comment: Why not just use SaveChanges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SaveChangesAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220070%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) returns a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you can just call [`Task.Wait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the point you need to make sure it's complete. You don't need to change the method to `async` in order to do this.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(#some argument)
{
  Task saveTask = null;
  ///so some computation and db operations without saving them
  bool shouldSave1 = doCalcs(onState);

  if (shouldSave1) {
    // here i want to save all the db operations i had done above
    saveTask = db.SaveChangesAsync(); //Task 1
  }

  // again do some computation 

  if (shouldSave1) {
    // wait for operation(Task1) to get complete
    saveTask.Wait(); // this blocks until the task completes
  }

  //do some computation
}
```

#### Footnote

This answer only shows you how to do this assuming you need to. In this particular situation (calling `SaveChangesAsync` directly within the action) it will work. It does not discuss if you should do it: there are many situations where `Wait`ing on the `Task` returned from an async method will deadlock the `ApiController` action's request context. The code below would therefore not be appropriate. See [Stephen Cleary: Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your reply, actually i was trying to do this by not using 'var', since in my code this is happening under some condition and i wanted to wait outside the scope of that condition

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just need a conditional save and a conditional wait? See above.

Comment: do we need to use
db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)? and instead of wait we should use await saveTask?

Comment: @AnshulNigam - to get proper answers you should ask those questions by themselves. The full answers are quite interesting so it might be worth asking them, but in short "no" (try it, you'll find the compiler error interesting) and "no" (unless you want to use `async` which you said you had to avoid in the original question)