# LINQ One-to–Zero-or-One is not UPDATING the record

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to update my database that is One-to–Zero-or-One using LINQ. (I'm using code first). The line "System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(await databaseConn.SaveChangesAsync());" return the value 0 instead of 1.

It supposed to return 1 because I'm updating the SOG of the currentTruck like this "currentTruck.Sog = newSog;"

DETAILS

DATABASES: TRUCK & SOG

SCENARIO : Truck has one SOG item, each truck should have only one SOG item, moreover some SOG will be without PARENT, in other words I can have:

TRUCK -> WITH SOG & TRUCK -> WITHOUT
SOG & SOG-> WITH TRUCK & SOG -> WITHOUT TRUCK.
TRUCK MODEL

```
[Key]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Truck ID")]
public string truck_id { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(10)]
[Display(Name = "REGO")]
public string truck_Rego { get; set; }

public int? subc_id { get; set; }

public virtual Subcontractor Subcontractor { get; set; }

public virtual Sog Sog { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<TruckServices> TruckServices { get; set; }
```

SOG MODEL

```
[Key, ForeignKey("Truck")]
public string truck_id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string sog_serialNumber { get; set; }

public virtual Truck Truck { get; set; }
```

I need to remove the current SOG item from the truck and add a new SOG item that is from another truck, in other words, TRUCK A has the SOG 1 and TRUCK B has the SOG 2, I need to remove the connection between the TRUCK B & SOG 2, and remove the connection between the TRUCK A & SOG 1 and after ADD the a connection between TRUCK A with the SOG 2.

I've used this tutorial (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-one-to-one-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) but it doesn't work, moreover I've tried the code below but nothing changes.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> truckAccount_SOG(string id, string _sog_IMEI)
{
    Truck   currentTruck        = await databaseConn.Trucks.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r=> r.truck_Rego.Equals(id)); 
    Sog     currentSog          = await databaseConn.Sogs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r=> r.truck_id.Equals(currentTruck.truck_id));
    Sog     newSog              = await databaseConn.Sogs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r=> r.sog_IMEI.Equals(_sog_IMEI));

    databaseConn.Entry(currentTruck).State  = EntityState.Modified;
    databaseConn.Entry(currentTruck).State  = EntityState.Detached;
    databaseConn.Entry(currentSog).State    = EntityState.Detached;
    databaseConn.Entry(newSog).State        = EntityState.Detached;

    currentTruck.Sog = newSog;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(await databaseConn.SaveChangesAsync());

    return null;
}
```

Is this relationship correct?

How can I update this record?

Does anyone has any example about how to use save/update ? I've found to one-to-zero-or-one that works

PS: I didn't check for Null Exception because for while I'm just testing and all the vars are valid.

Comment: `SaveChangesAsync` returns a `Task`, so you can just call `Task.Wait()` at the point you need to make sure it's complete. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825659/using-savechangesasync-feature-with-non-async-webapi

Comment: @Tim.Tang. Thank you!
I've removed all the ASYNC part and still returning 0.

Comment: When I try to save the data using the "databaseConn.SaveChanges()" it return the INT 0, that means nothing was change.